# Customise jqgrid delete dialog: Wrap message text in fixed with and remove autoscroll

Tags: jquery, jqgrid

I have been searching around to find how to customise the deletegridrow dialog. The first issue I have is that the form often stays open after the submit button is clicked.

Also, I'ld like to be able to wrap text within the dialog width instead of the horizontal scroll.

I will appreciate any help on this issue.

Comment: Which version of jqGrid you use and from which fork of jqGrid ([free jqGrid](https://github.com/free-jqgrid/jqGrid), commercial [Guriddo jqGrid JS](http://guriddo.net/?page_id=103334) or an old jqGrid in version <=4.7)? You should include the code which shows how you use/create Delete dialog and with which parameters. Wrong options (for example `afterSubmit` callback) is the typical reason of staying dialog opened.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I played with several versions of jqgrid but finally decided to use version 5.1.1 from github. I guess this is the old version. I was able to get the grid to close using this snipet

```js
            {
              caption: "Delete selected ISBN",
              modal: true,
              //msg : "The selected ISBN will be deleted from the system. Please confirm to proceed with this operation.",
              url: '<?php echo $this->Html->url(array('
              controller ' => '
              isbns ', '
              action ' => '
              delete ')); ?>',
              width: 300,
              closeOnEscape: true,
              reloadAfterSubmit: true,
              beforeShowForm: function($form) {
                row_id = $("#jqgrid").jqGrid('getGridParam', 'selrow');
                $("td.delmsg", $form[0]).html("Do you really want delete the isbn <br/>number: <b>" +
                  $("#jqgrid").jqGrid('getCell', row_id, 'isbn') + "</b>?");
              }
            }
```